# .NET Framework with Phone SDK confusion

Tags: windows-phone-8, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, intellisense, windows-phone-8-sdk

Currently I'm experience a very strange problem, which I can't solve by myself.

### Environment

- Windows 8.1
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 1
- Windows Phone 8 SDK
- ReSharper 8
- Xamarin (just to say, I don't think that this is the problem)

I've got a solution containing a single Windows Phone 8 project. Just one from the standard templates, nothing customized yet.
I've got a second solution containing a PCL project (call it *core* if you want). Both solutions/projects are currently independent, since I've got the following problem:

### The Problem

If I load the WP8-Solution, everything works as expected. The Visual Phone Designer loads and is working. Having IntelliSense as expected. Debugging on device and simulator works like a charm. Nothing curious.

The next step is to switch to the *core* solution, make some changes and switch back to the WP8 one.

Now the problems are starting. The Visual Phone Designer does not load due to a **markup error**. When looking in the xaml code, VS does not recognize anything related to the Windows 8 Phone SDK. IntelliSense stopped working, compilation fails, no start on device or simulator possible. It seems that VS stopped recognizing the project as a WP8 project.

It get's a bit more interesting now. When opening the .csproj file, the root is:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

Since I did't know what **ToolsVersion** exactly does, I looked it up in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383796.aspx). They also provide the registry key (*HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0*) where MSBuild finds the correct tools. After looking it up, I saw four entries: 12.0, 4.0, 3.5, 2.0.

For testing I changed `ToolsVersion="12.0"` to `ToolsVersion="4.0"` and reloaded the project. bingo: It is working again. It is working until I change to another solution or restart VS. Then I get the same errors again, as described.

The funny part is: If I change the ToolsVersion back to 12.0 it is working again until a solution change or VS restart.

It seems I can do this indefinitely. Very strange behavior.

### What I have tried so far

I uninstalled everything: Visual Studio, Resharper, Xamarin, Windows Phone 8 SDK. Run CCleaner (which did not help much I think), restarted the computer and installed everything again.

To be sure, that Resharper or Xamarin don't produce this error, I tried it at first without them and I still got it.

I'm not sure when exactly this kind of problem started, since I had developed some phone apps without that problem.

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it! The problem is getting annoying.

If you need more information, just drop me a comment.

Comment: Does the WP8 solution depend on the output of the second solution? You said the core was in a second solution, so that wouldn't affect the WP8 solution.

Comment: Currently it does not, since the projects are simple standard templates. I'll update the question with it. Thanks!

Comment: IF you have two copies of VS running -- what happens? Can you work that way?

Comment: Yes, this will work, as long as I don't close the one with the WP project. This would be a work around. Having the problem fixed would be better :)